# Squid blocks all traffic

Tags: ubuntu, squid

When I try to connect to squid, all traffic is blocked.

```
1344798323.392      0 192.168.1.188 TCP_DENIED/403 3631 CONNECT mail.google.com:443 - NONE/- text/html
```

### squid.conf

```
cache_mem 64 MB

cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid3 100 16 256

#Default:
# acl all src all
#
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
#acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8    # RFC1918 possible internal network
#acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.1.0/24 # RFC1918 possible internal network
#acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
#acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#
#Default:
# http_access deny all
#

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager

# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow localnet

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all


# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128 transparent

#Default:
# coredump_dir none
#

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid3


# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern (Release|Packages(.gz)*)$      0       20%     2880
# example lin deb packages
#refresh_pattern (\.deb|\.udeb)$   129600 100% 129600
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
```

Comment: All traffic?  To everywhere?  Or just Gmail over SSL?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, the solution to mine was to associate an IP address with the http_port. If it's on the local machine just make it 127.0.0.1:3128 transparent.

Answer (score -2):

Comment out "http_access deny !Safe_ports"